# Firewalld show rich rules without zone

Tags: debian, firewalld, nftables

May someone could help me with `firewalld`. I need to add rich rules with no associated zone, as the source / destination networks are all remote. For example:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="204.4.3.4" destination address="172.18.30.0/24" port port="80" protocol="tcp" accept'
```

Adding the rich rule is no problem, but how can i display it after creation? `firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules` kinda only works with a zone.

Comment: AFAIK, `firewalld` is built around the concept of zones. The [online manpage for firewall-cmd](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) indicates that `--zone=zone` is an optional parameter for `--list-rich-rules`. Can you cross-check with your local manpage?

Answer (score 0):

This works in Debian Bullseye (11)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="204.4.3.4" destination address="172.18.30.0/24" port port="80" protocol="tcp" accept'

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Adding the `permanent` flag causes it to target the non-ephemal firewall (the rules for which are listed) and also persist and then `firewall-cmd --list-rich rules` will show it.

Output:

```
rule family="ipv4" source address="204.4.3.4" destination address="172.18.30.0/24" port port="80" protocol="tcp" accept
```

The command does, in fact, add it to the default zone but you never stated that that wasn't what you wanted. Without the `--permanent` flag, nothing regarding the rule appears in any of the `firewall-cmd --list-<attribute>` commands or anywhere in `/etc/firewalld`. The only reason that I can devise for this is that it's ephemeral.

Comment: Wouldn't this command be adding the rich rule to the default zone, whichever that is?

Comment: @Haxiel Yes, but it was never stated that that wasn't wanted. See my update.